# Windows go blank when resizing

Tags: 11.10, drivers, graphics

Usually it happens when I make a window bigger.

[image]

[image]

I just updated to Ubuntu 11.10. I'm using an AMD Athlon and this is my driver's configuration:

[image]

(I remember I removed my video card though).

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: How much video memory do you have on the graphics adapter? Does the  screen redraw after the window has been resized so that it looks as it should look or does it remain blank?

Comment: This looks a lot like [bug 753144](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/753144).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going back to nvidia drivers version 173 fixed the problem.